# C# init keyword Get Or Set is Expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using below version of Visual Studio and trying to use C# 9.0 feature "[init](https://daveabrock.com/2020/06/29/c-sharp-9-deep-dive-inits)" but unfortunately seems like init is not understandable

Version

[image]

Error

[image]

Error is same in Vs 2019

[image]

Please help me out

Comment: `init` is a [C#9 proposal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/).

Comment: `init` is not C# 8 but C# 9

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay my bad , have updated the version

Comment: Does Visual Studio 2017 supports C#9?

Comment: Preview versions of recent versions of C# are supported only in VS 2019, and then only in recent versions of that ([instructions](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/08/07/getting-setup-with-c-9-preview/)). Whether or not support for C# 9 will be backported to VS 2017 when it comes out is not yet known.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  only for your reference see the last image and I can see 2019 not 2017

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions? On my VS 2019 Preview (16.7.0 preview 6.0), with the latest .NET 5 preview SDK installed, and a C# project with the language version set to "9.0" or "preview", I can compile a project that uses `init` (and the syntax highlighting works correctly as well).

Comment: ok @JeroenMostert I cross check al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#7 is the last version of language compatible with the classic .NET Framework. To use C#8 or test the preview C#9, you need target other .NET (like .NET Core).

More information :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

To test C#9, you need the last Visual Studio (work with 16.17.0) and the preview .NET 5. Create a new console project in .NET Core and edit your csproj :

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
-    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
+    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
+    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And enjoy the new sugar syntax keyword :)

(.NET 5 and C#9 are in preview, don't use the build result in production)

edit : If you have the error

> Error MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

In Visual Studio options, you need check the preview option and restart Visual Studio :

> Environment > Preview Features > Use previews of the .NET Core SDK

[image]